# Firebase Firestore & Cloud Functions - QuerySnapshot is not returned from Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Given the following code:

```
return admin.firestore()
    .collection("names")
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        var results = [];
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
            results.push(doc.id);
        })

        var promises = [];
        results.forEach(function(id){
            promises.push(admin.firestore().doc(`players/${id}`).get());
        }); 

        return Promise.all(promises);
    }).then(players => {
        players.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.data().name);
        });
        return players.docs.length; // undefined
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Why is it that `players` is not a `QuerySnapshot`? Iterating the `players` array does work and `doc.data().name` prints as expected but `docs` is not a property of `players`, thus indicating `players` is not a `QuerySnapshot`. How to solve this problem?